# Need to join two mySQL queries together if possible

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to combine these two queries to form one?

First Query:

```
SELECT products_options_values, options_values_price, orders_id
FROM orders_products_attributes oa
WHERE (products_options_id = 5 OR products_options_id = 1 OR products_options_id = 2)
AND oa.orders_id
IN (
SELECT DISTINCT o.orders_id
FROM orders o
WHERE o.ExportedToTradebox =  0
AND o.orders_id >  22000)
```

Second Query:

```
SELECT * FROM orders_products
WHERE orders_id 
IN(
SELECT DISTINCT orders_id 
FROM orders 
WHERE ExportedToTradebox='0' 
and orders_id >'22000')
```

I've tried several times and i just get SQL errors reported by phpMyAdmin
Sorry if it's something simple, my sql knowledge is very patchy.

Combined so that all the required information is brought into one array, when they are run. I have tried to use it from the two separate arrays it generates, but the php code in the program is poorly designed with multiple while loops along with else-if statements. Attempting to bring in yet another while-MoveNext loop just crashes everything. I figured if all the data can be collected to the original array it will be simple enough to echo the new fields.

Related DB table structures below:

Orders Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders` (
`orders_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`customers_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`customers_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`customers_company` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
`customers_street_address` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`customers_suburb` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`customers_city` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`customers_postcode` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`customers_state` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`customers_country` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`customers_telephone` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`customers_email_address` varchar(96) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`customers_address_format_id` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`delivery_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`delivery_company` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
`delivery_street_address` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`delivery_suburb` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`delivery_city` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`delivery_postcode` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`delivery_state` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`delivery_country` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`delivery_address_format_id` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`billing_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`billing_company` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
`billing_street_address` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`billing_suburb` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`billing_city` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`billing_postcode` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`billing_state` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`billing_country` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`billing_address_format_id` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`payment_method` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`payment_module_code` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`shipping_method` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`shipping_module_code` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`coupon_code` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`cc_type` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`cc_owner` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
`cc_number` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`cc_expires` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`cc_cvv` blob,
`last_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`date_purchased` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`orders_status` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`orders_date_finished` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`currency` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
`currency_value` decimal(14,6) DEFAULT NULL,
`order_total` decimal(14,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`order_tax` decimal(14,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`paypal_ipn_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`ip_address` varchar(96) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`ExportedToTradebox` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`orders_id`),
KEY `idx_status_orders_cust_zen` (`orders_status`,`orders_id`,`customers_id`),
KEY `idx_date_purchased_zen` (`date_purchased`),
KEY `idx_cust_id_orders_id_zen` (`customers_id`,`orders_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=23075 ;
```

Orders Attributes:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders_products_attributes` (
`orders_products_attributes_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`orders_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`orders_products_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`products_options` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`products_options_values` text NOT NULL,
`options_values_price` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
`price_prefix` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`product_attribute_is_free` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`products_attributes_weight` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`products_attributes_weight_prefix` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`attributes_discounted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`attributes_price_base_included` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`attributes_price_onetime` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
`attributes_price_factor` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
`attributes_price_factor_offset` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
`attributes_price_factor_onetime` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
`attributes_price_factor_onetime_offset` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
`attributes_qty_prices` text,
`attributes_qty_prices_onetime` text,
`attributes_price_words` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
`attributes_price_words_free` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`attributes_price_letters` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
`attributes_price_letters_free` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`products_options_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`products_options_values_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`products_prid` tinytext NOT NULL,
`tradebox_attributes_list` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`orders_products_attributes_id`),
KEY `idx_orders_id_prod_id_zen` (`orders_id`,`orders_products_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=77065 ;
```

Orders Products:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders_products` (
`orders_products_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`orders_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`products_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`products_model` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`products_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`products_price` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
`final_price` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
`products_tax` decimal(7,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
`products_quantity` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`onetime_charges` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
`products_priced_by_attribute` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`product_is_free` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`products_discount_type` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`products_discount_type_from` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`products_prid` tinytext NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`orders_products_id`),
KEY `idx_orders_id_prod_id_zen` (`orders_id`,`products_id`),
KEY `idx_prod_id_orders_id_zen` (`products_id`,`orders_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=34938 ;
```

Comment: How do you want them "combined"?  Please edit your post to give more detail.

Comment: What @AndyLester said.  Also, what columns are in your tables?  Post your DDL, please.

Comment: Also what columns do you want out? Are you expecting more than one orders_products_attributes per order?

Comment: @Greg There could be up to six orders_products_attributes per order, but we are primarily concerned with attributes 5, 1 & 2, being output in that order when displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *  --You can select your own columns later
    FROM orders_products_attributes oa
         RIGHT OUTER JOIN orders_products op
             ON oa.orders_products_id = op.orders_products_id
                 AND products_options_id IN (5, 1, 2)
    WHERE op.orders_id IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT o.orders_id
                FROM orders o
                WHERE o.ExportedToTradebox =  0
                    AND o.orders_id >  22000
        )
```

Presuming your order_products_ids reference the same piece of information, this will get you everything in one table.  You will have a row for each attribute, with the Order_Products Data Duplicated.  If you want information concatenated together, you can always try GROUP_CONCAT:

```
SELECT op.orders_products_id
        , GROUP_CONCAT(
          oa.products_options_id 
          ORDER BY CASE oa.products_options_id
              WHEN 5 THEN 1
              WHEN 1 THEN 2
              WHEN 2 THEN 3
              ELSE 4
          END ASC
          SEPARATOR '::'
        ) AS Options
    FROM orders_products_attributes oa
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN orders_products op
            ON oa.orders_products_id = op.orders_products_id
                AND oa.products_options_id IN (5, 1, 2)
    WHERE op.orders_id IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT o.orders_id
                FROM orders o
                WHERE o.ExportedToTradebox =  0
                    AND o.orders_id >  22000
        )
    GROUP BY op.orders_products_id
```

;

That'll get you a Comma Separated list.  Just sort of depends on what you need.

Comment: And if you want to Specify an order, you can change the ORDER BY to `ORDER BY CASE oa.orders_products_attributes_id WHEN 5 THEN 1 WHEN 1 THEN 2 WHEN 2 THEN 3 ELSE 4 END ASC`

Comment: I get an error when i try your second query: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY orders_products_attributes LIMIT 0, 30' at line 16

Comment: oops.  `GROUP BY orders_products_id` (the one at the end).  I'll edit the Question.

Comment: Still get a Syntax error. Looking at the query, it is short of a ) as it has 4 opening and 3 closing. If i add an extra closing ) at the end it doesn't give an error, but an example of the output is 
orders_products_id/Attributes
34813/[BLOB - 19B]
 Is that what i should expect?

Comment: Sorry, Steve, the opening Parenthesis after the WHERE is a typo.  Re-editing.

Comment: @StevePrice - I made a SQL Fiddle to do some debugging of my own, and wound up with much more useful information: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60d9d/14

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM orders_products op
LEFT JOIN orders_products_attributes oa
ON op.orders_id = oa.orders_id
WHERE (oa.products_options_id = 5 OR oa.products_options_id = 1 OR oa.products_options_id = 2)
AND oa.orders_id
IN (
SELECT DISTINCT o.orders_id
FROM orders o
WHERE o.ExportedToTradebox =  0
AND o.orders_id >  22000)
```

This will give you all the columns from those two tables in one result set. I used a left join so that if an orders_products record doesn't have an attribute then it will still be returned.

A problem you may face is if you got more than one `orders_product_attribute` per order id then you will duplicate the orders_products records. You may need to look at some sort of transpose function (I'm not sure how to do that in MySQL, or if it is even possible).

Comment: Just saw your comment on the question about the attributes. As I mentioned in my answer this will cause duplicate `orders_products` to appear

Comment: Already had that problem in another solution i tried unfortunately. It ended up showing the same order 4 times because it had four attributes selected for the product. I looked into using group_concat on the orders attributes but i don't think it can be combined with the current sql query. Somebody will correct me if i'm wrong on that, i'm sure!

Comment: I just ran your query in phpMyAdmin and it does indeed duplicate products if more than one attribute is assigned to it. I'm stumped at how to get around that one. I did think of having a query to pull in the attributes as a comma separated list, and then store them in a new field that could be called in original query, but it seems this isn't really an "acceptable" solution. I got some serious sideways looks when i suggested it.

Comment: yep, it will only work if you have 1 to 1 relation. Putting them all into one field isn't a great solution. @FrankieTheKneeMan's answer might work for you. Other alternative is to look at the pivot function. I normally work in MS SQL, not MySQL so I have no idea how to Pivot in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is UNION ALL:

```
SELECT products_options_values, options_values_price, orders_id 
FROM orders_products_attributes oa 
WHERE (products_options_id = 5 OR products_options_id = 1 OR products_options_id = 2) AND oa.orders_id IN ( SELECT DISTINCT o.orders_id FROM orders o WHERE o.ExportedToTradebox = 0 AND o.orders_id > 22000)
UNION ALL
SELECT products_options_values, options_values_price, order_number as orders_id 
FROM orders_products WHERE orders_id IN( SELECT DISTINCT orders_id FROM orders 
WHERE ExportedToTradebox='0' and orders_id >'22000')
```

Notice that I named the fields in the second query so that exactly match the names in the first query.

Comment: That was my thought at first, but I'm thinking a Join is more what OP is going for.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan  yeah, now that I look closer at his tables, you are probably right.  We'll have to see if he gives us his schema.