# MySQL query returns incorrect results

Tags: mysql

I had some advice from here regarding an SQL query i needed, but it now appears that it returns incorrect results if it comes across a product with no attributes assigned to it.
I will list the query below, along with a sample of the relevant db tables/data (data sanitized to remove client information).

Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders_products_attributes oa
INNER JOIN orders_products op ON oa.orders_id = op.orders_id
WHERE (
products_options_id
IN ( 1, 2 ) 
AND oa.orders_id
IN (
SELECT DISTINCT o.orders_id
FROM orders o
WHERE o.ExportedToTradebox =  0
AND o.orders_id >  22000))
```

DB:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
`orders_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`customers_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`customers_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`customers_company` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
`customers_street_address` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`customers_suburb` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`customers_city` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`customers_postcode` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`customers_state` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`customers_country` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`customers_telephone` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`customers_email_address` varchar(96) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`customers_address_format_id` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`delivery_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`delivery_company` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
`delivery_street_address` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`delivery_suburb` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`delivery_city` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`delivery_postcode` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`delivery_state` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`delivery_country` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`delivery_address_format_id` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`billing_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`billing_company` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
`billing_street_address` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`billing_suburb` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`billing_city` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`billing_postcode` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`billing_state` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`billing_country` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`billing_address_format_id` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`payment_method` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`payment_module_code` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`shipping_method` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`shipping_module_code` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`coupon_code` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`cc_type` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
`cc_owner` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
`cc_number` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`cc_expires` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`cc_cvv` blob,
`last_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`date_purchased` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`orders_status` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`orders_date_finished` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`currency` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
`currency_value` decimal(14,6) DEFAULT NULL,
`order_total` decimal(14,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`order_tax` decimal(14,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`paypal_ipn_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`ip_address` varchar(96) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`ExportedToTradebox` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`orders_id`),
KEY `idx_status_orders_cust_zen` (`orders_status`,`orders_id`,`customers_id`),
KEY `idx_date_purchased_zen` (`date_purchased`),
KEY `idx_cust_id_orders_id_zen` (`customers_id`,`orders_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=23161  

INSERT INTO `orders` VALUES (23110, 5801, 'Customer One', '', 'Any BUilding', '', 'Any       Town', 'AN0 1TH', 'Lancashire', 'United Kingdom (Mainland)', '01234567890', 'email@customer.com', 6, 'Customer One', '', 'Any Building', 'Any Street', 'Any Town', 'AN0 1TH', 'Lancashire', 'United Kingdom (Mainland)', 6, 'Customer One', '', 'Any Building', 'Any Street', 'Any Town', 'AN0 1TH', 'Lancashire', 'United Kingdom (Mainland)', 6, 'Credit/Debit Card (Secured by Sage Pay)', 'ceon_sage_pay_direct', 'Table Rate (Best Way)', 'table', '', 'Visa', 'Customer One', 'XXXXXXXXXX', '0515', NULL, NULL, '2013-01-10 09:57:51', 1, NULL, 'GBP', 1.000000, 16.14, 2.69, 0, '88.96.93.217 - 88.96.93.217', 1);
INSERT INTO `orders` VALUES (23111, 11361, 'Customer Two', '', 'Any Street', '', 'Any Town', 'AN0 1TH', 'Cumbria', 'United Kingdom (Mainland)', '01234567890', 'email@customer.com', 6, 'Customer Two', '', 'Any Street', '', 'Any Town', 'AN0 1TH', 'Cumbria', 'United Kingdom (Mainland)', 6, 'Customer Two', '', 'Any Street', '', 'Any Town', 'AN0 1TH', 'Cumbria', 'United Kingdom (Mainland)', 6, 'Credit/Debit Card (Secured by Sage Pay)', 'ceon_sage_pay_direct', 'Table Rate (Best Way)', 'table', '', 'MasterCard', 'Customer Two', 'XXXXXXXXXX', '0713', NULL, NULL, '2013-01-10 18:29:23', 1, NULL, 'GBP', 1.000000, 25.50, 4.25, 0, '86.179.13.89 - 86.179.13.89', 0);
INSERT INTO `orders` VALUES (23112, 23787, 'Customer Three', '', 'Any Street', 'Any Town', 'SWANSEA', 'AN0 1TH', 'Swansea', 'United Kingdom (Mainland)', '01234567890', 'email@customer.com', 6, 'Customer Three', '', 'Any Street', '', 'Any Town', 'AN0 1TH', 'Kent', 'United Kingdom (Mainland)', 6, 'Customer Three', '', 'Any Street', 'Any Town', 'SWANSEA', 'AN0 1TH', 'Swansea', 'United Kingdom (Mainland)', 6, 'Credit/Debit Card (Secured by Sage Pay)', 'ceon_sage_pay_direct', 'Table Rate (Best Way)', 'table', '', 'MasterCard', 'Customer Three', 'XXXXXXXXXX', '0314', NULL, NULL, '2013-01-10 20:27:12', 1, NULL, 'GBP', 1.000000, 15.48, 2.58, 0, '176.24.1.143 - 176.24.1.143', 1);
INSERT INTO `orders` VALUES (23113, 23788, 'Customer Four, '', 'Any Street', 'Any Town', 'Reading', 'AN0 1TH', 'Berkshire', 'United Kingdom (Mainland)', '01234567890', 'email@customer.com', 6, 'Customer Four', '', 'Any Building', 'Any Street', 'Any Town', 'AN0 1TH', 'Berkshire', 'United Kingdom (Mainland)', 6, 'Customer Four', '', 'Any Street', 'Any Town', 'Reading', 'AN0 1TH', 'Berkshire', 'United Kingdom (Mainland)', 6, 'Credit/Debit Card (Secured by Sage Pay)', 'ceon_sage_pay_direct', 'Table Rate (Best Way)', 'table', '', 'Visa Debit', 'Customer Four', 'XXXXXXXXXX', '0315', NULL, NULL, '2013-01-10 22:52:17', 1, NULL, 'GBP', 1.000000, 19.74, 3.29, 0, '80.7.137.154 - 80.7.137.154', 1);
INSERT INTO `orders` VALUES (23114, 15693, 'Customer Five', '', 'Any Street', 'Any Town', 'Londonderry', 'AN0 1TH', 'Londonderry', 'United Kingdom (Mainland)', '01234567890', 'email@customer.com', 6, 'Customer Five', '', 'Any Street', 'Any Town', 'Londonderry', 'AN0 1TH', 'Londonderry', 'United Kingdom (Mainland)', 6, 'Customer Five', '', 'Any Street', 'Any Town', 'Londonderry', 'AN0 1TH', 'Londonderry', 'United Kingdom (Mainland)', 6, 'Credit/Debit Card (Secured by Sage Pay)', 'ceon_sage_pay_direct', 'Table Rate (Best Way)', 'table', '', 'Visa', 'Customer Five', 'XXXXXXXXXX', '0715', NULL, NULL, '2013-01-11 08:53:07', 1, NULL, 'GBP', 1.000000, 19.38, 3.23, 0, '92.17.232.252 - 92.17.232.252', 1);
INSERT INTO `orders` VALUES (23115, 23790, 'Customer Six', '', 'Any Street', 'Any Town', 'Huddersfield', 'AN0 1TH', 'West Yorkshire', 'United Kingdom (Mainland)', '01234567890', 'email@customer.com', 6, 'Customer Six', '', 'Any Street', 'Any Town', 'Huddersfield', 'AN0 1TH', 'West Yorkshire', 'United Kingdom (Mainland)', 6, 'Customer Six', '', 'Any Street', 'Any Town', 'Huddersfield', 'AN0 1TH', 'West Yorkshire', 'United Kingdom (Mainland)', 6, 'Credit/Debit Card (Secured by Sage Pay)', 'ceon_sage_pay_direct', 'Table Rate (Best Way)', 'table', '', 'Visa Debit', 'Customer Six', 'XXXXXXXXXX', '1214', NULL, NULL, '2013-01-11 12:50:34', 1, NULL, 'GBP', 1.000000, 428.40, 119.00, 0, '109.237.17.198 - 109.237.17.198', 1);


CREATE TABLE `orders_products` (
`orders_products_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`orders_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`products_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`products_model` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`products_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`products_price` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
`final_price` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
`products_tax` decimal(7,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
`products_quantity` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`onetime_charges` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
`products_priced_by_attribute` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`product_is_free` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`products_discount_type` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`products_discount_type_from` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`products_prid` tinytext NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`orders_products_id`),
KEY `idx_orders_id_prod_id_zen` (`orders_id`,`products_id`),
KEY `idx_prod_id_orders_id_zen` (`products_id`,`orders_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=35040 ;



INSERT INTO `orders_products` VALUES (34978, 23110, 31, '', 'A4 Teacher''s Planner', 10.5000, 10.5000, 20.0000, 1, 0.0000, 0, 0, 0, 0, '31:9964928c32c2a3849188981afa12a093');
INSERT INTO `orders_products` VALUES (34979, 23111, 46, '', 'Custom Built A5 Teacher''s Planner', 9.6000, 13.9000, 20.0000, 1, 0.0000, 0, 0, 0, 0, '46:ba39091f0bf22bf2e10c81adc942e4e1');
INSERT INTO `orders_products` VALUES (34980, 23111, 23, '', 'Notes Book (NB)', 3.5000, 3.5000, 20.0000, 1, 0.0000, 0, 0, 0, 0, '23:eb5397bb218cc175011cd7789237bd50');
INSERT INTO `orders_products` VALUES (34981, 23111, 21, '', 'Wall Chart 2013-2014 (CH34)', 0.9000, 0.9000, 20.0000, 1, 0.0000, 0, 0, 0, 0, '21');
INSERT INTO `orders_products` VALUES (34982, 23112, 46, '', 'Custom Built A5 Teacher''s Planner', 9.6000, 9.9500, 20.0000, 1, 0.0000, 0, 0, 0, 0, '46:f9cc81aecfe9f185caeaaefa16d74bb3');
INSERT INTO `orders_products` VALUES (34983, 23113, 49, '', 'Custom Built Primary Teacher''s Planner', 12.5000, 13.5000, 20.0000, 1, 0.0000, 0, 0, 0, 0, '49:265721a8b48ba787e0109dae30acb7b4');
INSERT INTO `orders_products` VALUES (34984, 23114, 30, '', 'Custom Built A4 Teacher''s Planner', 12.5000, 13.2000, 20.0000, 1, 0.0000, 0, 0, 0, 0, '30:b0018c6b89bd8efbbfa3dcd3a5c4a2ff');
INSERT INTO `orders_products` VALUES (34985, 23115, 22, '', 'Visitors Book (VB)', 5.9500, 5.9500, 20.0000, 100, 0.0000, 0, 0, 0, 0, '22:a2bedb3944abb52dd530db1c8e05b3b9');


CREATE TABLE `orders_products_attributes` (
`orders_products_attributes_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`orders_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`orders_products_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`products_options` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`products_options_values` text NOT NULL,
`options_values_price` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
`price_prefix` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`product_attribute_is_free` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`products_attributes_weight` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`products_attributes_weight_prefix` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`attributes_discounted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`attributes_price_base_included` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`attributes_price_onetime` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
`attributes_price_factor` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
`attributes_price_factor_offset` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
`attributes_price_factor_onetime` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
`attributes_price_factor_onetime_offset` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
`attributes_qty_prices` text,
`attributes_qty_prices_onetime` text,
`attributes_price_words` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
`attributes_price_words_free` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`attributes_price_letters` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
`attributes_price_letters_free` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`products_options_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`products_options_values_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`products_prid` tinytext NOT NULL,
`tradebox_attributes_list` text NOT NULL,
`tradebox_options_price_list` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
PRIMARY KEY (`orders_products_attributes_id`),
KEY `idx_orders_id_prod_id_zen` (`orders_id`,`orders_products_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=77370 ;


INSERT INTO `orders_products_attributes` VALUES (77193, 23110, 34978, 'Lesson format', '9 period day (TP9)', 0.0000, '+', 1, 0, '+', 1, 1, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, '', '', 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 5, 57, '31:9964928c32c2a3849188981afa12a093', '', 0.0000);
INSERT INTO `orders_products_attributes` VALUES (77194, 23110, 34978, 'Cover', 'Navy (blue wire)', 0.0000, '+', 1, 0, '+', 1, 1, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, '', '', 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 1, 74, '31:9964928c32c2a3849188981afa12a093', '9 period day (TP9), Navy (blue wire)', 0.0000);
INSERT INTO `orders_products_attributes` VALUES (77195, 23111, 34979, 'Lesson format', '5 period day (TP5)', 0.0000, '+', 1, 0, '+', 1, 1, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, '', '', 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 5, 54, '46:ba39091f0bf22bf2e10c81adc942e4e1', '', 0.0000);
INSERT INTO `orders_products_attributes` VALUES (77196, 23111, 34979, 'Cover', 'Navy', 0.0000, '+', 1, 0, '+', 1, 1, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, '', '', 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 1, 2, '46:ba39091f0bf22bf2e10c81adc942e4e1', 'Navy', 1.0000);
INSERT INTO `orders_products_attributes` VALUES (77197, 23111, 34979, 'Wire', 'Fluorescent Yellow (f)', 0.0000, '', 1, 0, '', 1, 1, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, '', '', 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 4, 51, '46:ba39091f0bf22bf2e10c81adc942e4e1', '', 0.0000);
INSERT INTO `orders_products_attributes` VALUES (77198, 23111, 34979, 'Ribbon', 'Fuschia (7)', 0.0000, '+', 1, 0, '+', 1, 1, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, '', '', 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 3, 19, '46:ba39091f0bf22bf2e10c81adc942e4e1', '', 0.0000);
INSERT INTO `orders_products_attributes` VALUES (77199, 23111, 34979, 'Initials (Max 4)', 'DBI', 3.3000, '+', 1, 0, '+', 1, 1, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, '', '', 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 2, 0, '46:ba39091f0bf22bf2e10c81adc942e4e1', 'DBI', 0.0000);
INSERT INTO `orders_products_attributes` VALUES (77200, 23111, 34979, 'Plastic pockets', '2 at front, 2 at back', 1.0000, '+', 1, 0, '+', 1, 1, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, '', '', 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 6, 87, '46:ba39091f0bf22bf2e10c81adc942e4e1', '', 0.0000);
INSERT INTO `orders_products_attributes` VALUES (77201, 23111, 34980, 'Cover', 'Navy', 0.0000, '+', 1, 0, '+', 1, 1, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, '', '', 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 1, 2, '23:eb5397bb218cc175011cd7789237bd50', 'Navy', 1.0000);
INSERT INTO `orders_products_attributes` VALUES (77202, 23112, 34982, 'Lesson format', '6 period day (TP6)', 0.0000, '+', 1, 0, '+', 1, 1, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, '', '', 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 5, 55, '46:f9cc81aecfe9f185caeaaefa16d74bb3', '', 0.0000);
INSERT INTO `orders_products_attributes` VALUES (77203, 23112, 34982, 'Cover', 'Yellow', 0.0000, '+', 1, 0, '+', 1, 1, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, '', '', 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 1, 10, '46:f9cc81aecfe9f185caeaaefa16d74bb3', '6 period day (TP6), Yellow, 2 at back', 0.3500);
INSERT INTO `orders_products_attributes` VALUES (77204, 23112, 34982, 'Wire', 'Silver (i)', 0.0000, '', 1, 0, '', 1, 1, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, '', '', 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 4, 50, '46:f9cc81aecfe9f185caeaaefa16d74bb3', '', 0.0000);
INSERT INTO `orders_products_attributes` VALUES (77205, 23112, 34982, 'Ribbon', 'Black (5)', 0.0000, '+', 1, 0, '+', 1, 1, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, '', '', 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 3, 17, '46:f9cc81aecfe9f185caeaaefa16d74bb3', '', 0.0000);
INSERT INTO `orders_products_attributes` VALUES (77206, 23112, 34982, 'Plastic pockets', '2 at back', 0.3500, '+', 1, 0, '+', 1, 1, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, '', '', 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 6, 85, '46:f9cc81aecfe9f185caeaaefa16d74bb3', '', 0.0000);
INSERT INTO `orders_products_attributes` VALUES (77207, 23113, 34983, 'Lesson format', '3 period (2 morning, 1 afternoon)', 0.0000, '+', 1, 0, '+', 1, 1, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, '', '', 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 5, 59, '49:265721a8b48ba787e0109dae30acb7b4', '', 0.0000);
INSERT INTO `orders_products_attributes` VALUES (77208, 23113, 34983, 'Cover', 'Pink', 0.0000, '+', 1, 0, '+', 1, 1, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, '', '', 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 1, 8, '49:265721a8b48ba787e0109dae30acb7b4', '3 period (2 morning, 1 afternoon), Pink, 2 at front, 2 at back', 1.0000);
INSERT INTO `orders_products_attributes` VALUES (77209, 23113, 34983, 'Wire', 'Blue (c)', 0.0000, '', 1, 0, '', 1, 1, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, '', '', 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 4, 47, '49:265721a8b48ba787e0109dae30acb7b4', '', 0.0000);
INSERT INTO `orders_products_attributes` VALUES (77210, 23113, 34983, 'Ribbon', 'Dorothy (34)', 0.0000, '+', 1, 0, '+', 1, 1, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, '', '', 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 3, 81, '49:265721a8b48ba787e0109dae30acb7b4', '', 0.0000);
INSERT INTO `orders_products_attributes` VALUES (77211, 23113, 34983, 'Plastic pockets', '2 at front, 2 at back', 1.0000, '+', 1, 0, '+', 1, 1, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, '', '', 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 6, 87, '49:265721a8b48ba787e0109dae30acb7b4', '', 0.0000);
INSERT INTO `orders_products_attributes` VALUES (77212, 23114, 34984, 'Lesson format', '8 period day (TP8)', 0.0000, '+', 1, 0, '+', 1, 1, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, '', '', 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 5, 56, '30:b0018c6b89bd8efbbfa3dcd3a5c4a2ff', '', 0.0000);
INSERT INTO `orders_products_attributes` VALUES (77213, 23114, 34984, 'Cover', 'Purple', 0.0000, '+', 1, 0, '+', 1, 1, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, '', '', 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 1, 7, '30:b0018c6b89bd8efbbfa3dcd3a5c4a2ff', '8 period day (TP8), Purple, 1 at front, 2 at back', 0.7000);
INSERT INTO `orders_products_attributes` VALUES (77214, 23114, 34984, 'Wire', 'Metallic Red (g)', 0.0000, '', 1, 0, '', 1, 1, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, '', '', 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 4, 52, '30:b0018c6b89bd8efbbfa3dcd3a5c4a2ff', '', 0.0000);
INSERT INTO `orders_products_attributes` VALUES (77215, 23114, 34984, 'Ribbon', 'Gold Lamé (17)', 0.0000, '+', 1, 0, '+', 1, 1, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, '', '', 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 3, 29, '30:b0018c6b89bd8efbbfa3dcd3a5c4a2ff', '', 0.0000);
INSERT INTO `orders_products_attributes` VALUES (77216, 23114, 34984, 'Plastic pockets', '1 at front, 2 at back', 0.7000, '+', 1, 0, '+', 1, 1, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, '', '', 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 6, 86, '30:b0018c6b89bd8efbbfa3dcd3a5c4a2ff', '', 0.0000);
INSERT INTO `orders_products_attributes` VALUES (77217, 23115, 34985, 'Cover', 'Burgundy', 0.0000, '+', 1, 0, '+', 1, 1, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, '', '', 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 1, 1, '22:a2bedb3944abb52dd530db1c8e05b3b9', 'Burgundy', 0.0000);
```

The original query used to be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders_products 
WHERE orders_id 
IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT orders_id 
    FROM orders 
    WHERE ExportedToTradebox='0' and orders_id >'0'
)
```

Order number 23111 is where the problem is. The wall chart ordered does not have attributes, and yet when the db is queried it applies the attributes listed for other items in the order.

Schema for the relevant data is to be found at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0003
I have only included the data for order number 23111 in there.

The query passes the results to an xml file. Results are shown below:

1 Custom Built A5 Teachers Planner|Navy     13.90     2.95
1 Custom Built A5 Teachers Planner|DBI       3.30     0.00
1 Custom Built A5 Teachers Planner|Navy     13.90     2.95
1 NotesBook(NB)|Navy                         3.50     0.00
1 NotesBook(NB)|DBI                          3.50     0.00
1 NotesBook(NB)|Navy                         3.50     0.00
1 Wall Chart 2013-2014|Navy                  0.90     0.00
1 Wall Chart 2013-2014|DBI                   0.90     0.00
1 Wall Chart 2013-2014|Navy                  0.90     0.00

As it should be:

1 Custom Built A5 Teachers Planner|Navy     13.90     2.95
1 Custom Built A5 Teachers Planner|DBI       3.30     0.00
1 NotesBook(NB)|Navy                         3.50     0.00
1 Wall Chart 2013-2014                       0.90     0.00

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

DRapp provided an almost working solution to this, however, although the query returns correct results, in use it creates problems in that calling the orders_id from the results gives no orders id for products without attributes. This is most likely caused by the way the tables are joined. If a product has no attributes then it won't be in the orders_products_attributes table and therefore the order id returns NULL on these products which means they do not get processed by the code that follows.

Comment: Just off the cuff, your query looks strange and overly complicated. Please state what you are trying to achieve with the query. Also, please move your schema onto an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) and post it's link into your question, so people can easily try their queries against your data. Finally, please show the results you are expecting with thus data.

Comment: I don't think this query is doing you any favours. Consider providing representative DDLs (CREATE and INSERT statements) for ALL relevant tables, together with the desired result set. Consider also, reducing your problem down to only the most pertinent columns.

Comment: I posted the relevant db tables and sample data as last time i posted an sql question i was asked to provide this data. The above query was a solution provided by a member on here and was the only one that actually worked at the time, hence it being used.

Comment: @Bohemian The query was written by FrankieTheKneeMan and up until the point where it was processing products without attributes it functioned perfectly well. The original problem is documented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225828/need-to-join-two-mysql-queries-together-if-possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would adjust slightly.  First, start with a prequery of all possible orders you want to include.   Ensure you have an index to help optimize. I would have index on (ExportedToTradeBox, Orders_ID).

So, now I have a prequery result set of "OnlyThese".  Now, join to the products as all orders have a product, but all products do not require an attribute option.

THEN, do a LEFT-JOIN to the order product attribute table, but only on the keys that join them (ensuring proper order AND product).  So now, you have a query of all qualified orders and joined to the ultimate product attributes table regardless of having an attribute or not.

Finally, apply the WHERE clause as NULL OR being one of the types you are expecting.  This way, it looks at each item and asks.  If there IS NO Option, allow it... However, if it DOES have an attribute, I only want those with an option of 1 or 2 (via the IN (1,2) clause).

```
SELECT 
      *  (actual column list you want) 
   FROM 
      ( SELECT DISTINCT o.orders_id
           FROM orders o
           WHERE o.ExportedToTradebox =  0
           AND o.orders_id >  22000) OnlyThese
         JOIN orders_products op 
            ON OnlyThese.orders_id = op.orders_id
            LEFT JOIN orders_products_attributes oa
               ON op.Orders_ID = oa.Orders_ID
               AND op.orders_products_id = oa.orders_products_id
   WHERE
         oa.products_options_id IS NULL
      OR oa.products_options_id IN ( 1, 2 )
```

Comment: I tried to use the query suggested but i just get errors. Unknown column 'oa.orders_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: @StevePrice, I had wrong alias... revised to "OnlyThese.Orders_ID = op.orders_id"... must have left from paste from your original query.

Comment: The query returns correct results, however, in use it creates problems in that calling the orders_id from the results gives no orders id for products without attributes. This is most likely caused by the way the tables are joined. If a product has no attributes then it won't be in the orders_products_attributes table and therefore the order id returns NULL on these products which means they do not get processed by the code that follows.

Comment: I resolved this issue with a separate query, but on the whole, your answer was a huge help. Thank you